# Boss-Worker model design

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, worker-process

I am developing a code using Boss-Worker model pattern. I have a doubt.
The list which the Boss will be adding to, is a member of the Boss class.
In order for the Worker to access it, I am making the Worker class inherit from Boss.

1)  Is this the right way to share the list between the Boss & Worker?
2)  I am facing ambiguous inheritance in my code. How can I solve it?

**ThreadClass**

```
#include <pthread.h>
class ThreadClass
{
public:
    virtual int start();
    virtual void join();
    virtual void execute() = 0; //Each derived class will implement this
    virtual ~ThreadClass() {}
    ThreadClass() {}
private:
    ThreadClass* Tptr;
};
```

**Boss**

```
#include "ThreadClass.h"
#include <list>

class Boss : public virtual ThreadClass
{
public:
    virtual void execute();
    Boss() {}   
    ~Boss() {}  

protected:
    std::list<int> Mylist;   //To be shared with the worker
};
```

**Worker**

```
#include "ThreadClass.h"
#include "Boss.h"
class Worker : public Boss, public ThreadClass  //Getting error:Ambiguous ThreadClass
{
public:
    virtual void execute();
    Worker() {} 
    ~Worker() {}    
};
```

Worker is inheriting from Boss & ThreadClass because:

1)  Worker needs access to the list from Boss
2)  Worker needs threading functions from ThreadClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The list which the Boss will be adding to, is a member of the Boss class. In order for the Worker to access it, I am making the Worker class inherit from Boss.

This is categorically *not* a good reason for one class to inherit from another. Usually, `Worker` should inherit from `Boss` if and only if you can substitute a `Worker` in any place that you could use a `Boss`. Conceptually, this is not the case here.

If you want to provide access to `Boss`'s list of `int` then, if the `Worker` knows about the `Boss` provide and accessor for it in `Boss` or (possibly) make `Worker` a `friend` of `Boss`.

If you don't want `Worker` to know about `Boss` but instead have `Boss` know about `Worker`s then make `Boss` pass the list to the `Worker` either at construction time or at a suitable time later.

Providing access to something is not a reason for making one class derive from another.

Comment: I got your point. Worker "is not a" Boss to inherit from him.

Answer (score 1):

I would de-couple all the classes and favour composition. Both `Worker` and `Boss` can share an externally created list, by holding a reference to it. Concerning the thread functionality, the C++11 and boost.thread approach is to have thread types that take "callable" entities. I think this de-coupled approach is cleaner than the double inheritance you propose.

By the way, you may need to roll out your own concurrent list class for this. `std::list` will not be safe against writes from at least one of the threads threads, if a different threads are reading concurrently.

```
class ConcurrentList { .... };
class Boss
{
  ConcurrentList& list_;
 public:
  Boss(ConcurrentList& l) : list_(l)
  // other methods
};
class Worker
{
  ConcurrentList& list_;

 public:
  Worker(ConcurrentList& l) : list_(l)
  // other methods
};
class Thread
{
  // implement a call-cack mechanism
};
```

Comment: If the write is done by only 1 thread and multiple threads read from the list, `std::list` would suffice right?

Comment: @cppcoder I don't think so, because the reads are not atomic. You could be reading a location at the same time as another thread modifies it.